# Installing a "key cylinder" to open and close the garage door

Tags: electrical, wiring, garage-door-opener

I have a Chamberlain LiftMaster Professional Garage Door opener (June 2007) with a wireless keypad to open the door but does not open consistently in cold weather. I would like to install a hardwired "key" solution so that the garage door opens consistently in all weather. Can this be done? Is there a specific cylinder I need to purchase for this task?

thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that a hardwired key means the wires will have to be physically present at that location, so it makes it a very easy target for someone that wants to get in the garage.  These keys were common in houses I've seen built in the 80's but I haven't noticed many lately.

Comment: The keypads should be designed to work in all weather, but perhaps your battery isn't up to snuff. Look for batteries designed to deal with cold weather.

Comment: Look for Lithium AAA or AA batteries.  These hold up in cold weather.  I use them in outdoor temperature sensors and a gate opener.  They are expensive, but they do last a long time.

Comment: You'd need a momentary key switch, with a spring return, so that you can momentarily close the contacts rather than switching them long-term on or off.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your opener has the terminals for doing so, to hardwire this you would want either a double-momentary keyswitch, or a housing that takes a lock cylinder and uses its tailpiece to actuate a pair of momentary switches, plus appropriate mounting hardware and wires. The latter gives you more flexibility in picking a cylinder that matches, e.g., your house keys.

I agree that if the battery is good, and is appropriate for that weather, and there isn't an unreasonable amount of radio frequency interference (RFI) with the signal, a decent quality numeric pad should work. You may want to spend more time checking why it doesn't before investing in the wired switch.

Answer (score 1):

Why not grab some interior standard outlet (120VAC), plug a 3 VDC transformer/converter in, and feed the battery connections directly inside the keypad?  That guarantees plenty of power and avoids a rather messy job (installing a mechanical momentary keyswitch).